# Does downsizing an image using height and width attributes of <img> tag in HTML waste bandwidth?

Tags: html, image

I'va an image 'Angelina.png' having resolution 1000x1000, which is to be rendered as 50x50 on webpage. Does the following have same affect as it would have been for the case if the image itself was 50x50? Or, does it waste the user bandwidth by downloading the original size?

`<img src='Angelina.png' width='50px' height='50px' alt='Angelina' />`

Comment: For effective rendering of images, which goes beyond your question, this is interesting: http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/

Comment: It will not resize the image.  It will download the full size version and then display it at reduced size.  You need a resized version on the server, or a server-side solution to resize it for you.  It's easiest to just resize it and have the thumbnail and the original available.

Comment: On very high resolution displays (or printers), using a larger image will look better, because such displays have multiple device dots per (logical) pixel. In your example however, you would need a ***very*** high resolution to take advantage of the full image; at least 2000dpi. We haven't advanced that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since you are resizing email on DOM i.e in actual image is downloaded from the server (with the actual size) and you are simply trying to resize it on DOM to improve the UI.

Comment: I think it does answer the question? OP is wondering if specifying the attributes on the `img` tag will waste bandwidth, and this answer clarifies that it does. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it goes:

> Tip: Downsizing a large image with the height and width attributes forces a user to download the large image (even if it looks small on the page). To avoid this, rescale the image with a program before using it on a page.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp

So, the answer is yes, it takes more time to download, wastes bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If bandwidth is your concern re-size it server side using php GD before downloading. As Guru Kamar said html is executed client side so image is downloaded then resized.  PHP is executed server side so downloaded image would be smaller.  Yes it wastes bandwidth.